# Sorting non-English names with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, non-english

I am trying to sort a table that contains Greek characters. The corresponding English version of the table is being sorted (both `ASC` and `DESC`) just fine, every time you click on the header of the table.

I have searched on Greek forums and the only solution suggested is to use `ORDER BY BINARY`. In fact, many people said that the use of binary order solved their problem. Unfortunately, it doesn't in my case. I know that the same problem exists in with languages like German where the use of umlauts messes the order and in general in languages with special caracters. If someone has any idea how to overcome this problem i would be grateful.

Comment: From what I know from Hebrew, non-latin languages are sorted by their ASCII (or Unicode) index, which generally should work with languages like Greek. So I don't see where the problem lies. Could you focus your question?

Comment: I have changed your [tag:PHP] tag to [tag:MySQL] since this has nothing to do with PHP. Also, could you give an example of something that doesn't sort well? Just a few names. What [charset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html) is your table?

Comment: The problem is that i dont get the right order. For example words beginning with ,A that is even in greek the first letter of the alphabet, they appear almost at the end of my table. I am not very expert of PHP and now i am thinking if the collation of the table is the problem?

Comment: What character set and collation do these fields have?

Comment: UTF-8 is the character set. utf8_general_ci is the collation. When is set the collation to greek i see question marks instead of letters.

Comment: Are you expecting the Greek Α (capital alpha) to appear with Latin A (capital a)? Because it won't — it will appear somewhere after Latin Z (capital z).

Comment: The greek names and english names are sorted separately according to the language selected. So i dont expect greek A to be with latin A, i expect it before greek gamma Γ (third letter of the alphabet). Infact names starting with greek gamma appear before everything else on my list.

Comment: First of all thank all of you for bothering answering to me and help me think torwards the right direcction.  So the initial comment of the user Truth was correct. I changed the collation of the table to  utf8_unicode_ci and everything is in the right order even in greek. 
Thank you all!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [a thread on forums.mysql.com](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,170576,203786), in MySQL 6.0, you can sort Greek names if the charset of your table is set to `utf8_general_ci`.

```
create table t (s1 char(1) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci); 
insert into t values ('Α'),('Β'),('Γ'),('Δ'),('Ε'),('Ζ');
select * from t order by s1;
```

The above should return

```
+----+ 
| s1 | 
+----+ 
| Α  | 
| Β  | 
| Γ  | 
| Δ  | 
| Ε  | 
| Ζ  |
+----+
```

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.1.53. You suggest that i should upgrade to the latest one?

Comment: @user926652, it doesn't work on MySQL 5.1.x, but it does on MySQL 6 - That's all I can say. Whether you should upgrade, I can't tell. It appears to be in an early stage of development, so it might not be a good idea - but it will solve _this_ problem.